# getting the measurement of tiles that together make up a floor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

Basically the question goes something like this: A floor of length 16m and width 4m is covered with tiles.
The tiles are square tiles.
You are required to find the area of the tiles and the number of tiles used.Sometimes they might ask you to find the greatest area of the tiles.
So far this is how I could reason it.

Area of floor 16*4=64

Area of tile:x*x=x^2

64/(x^2)=number of tiles.

Then I realise I have 2 unknowns.

So I get the perimeter 2(16+4)=40

So the perimeter of one tile multiplied by the number of tiles gives the perimeter of the larger one.

(x^ 2)*n=64  //the area of one tile multiplied by the number of tiles.Equation 1

2x*n=40 //the perimeter of one tile multipled by the number of tiles should give you the perimeter of the larger one.Equation 2

For the perimeter n=20\x

So now just replace the n in Equation 2

You will eventually reach 64=20x

X=3.2

But all this is based on a great assumption I made.That the perimeter of 1 tile multiplied by the number of tiles gives the perimeter of the floor.

Something feels wrong about this assumption.Is what I have done correct, if not please show me another way of doing it.

Comment: You are indeed wrong; you cannot multiply the perimeter by the number of tiles to get the larger perimeter.

Comment: Then how else would you do the question? Because I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Perimeter is not relevant. **If** all tiles are the same size, each tile can be $\frac{4}{n}$ by $\frac{4}{n}$ for any positive integer $n$. Of course it might be tough to find suitable tiles if $n=10^{8}$. And we are forgetting about the grout.

Comment: What does $\frac{4}{n}$ by $\frac{4}{n}$ mean Andre? Is that high school math?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider each dimension separately.

In $x$ dimension you have $4\over x$ tiles.

In $y$ dimension you have $16\over x$ tiles.

Both of them must be integers so $x=1,2,4$ are the only possibilities.

The greatest area of one tile is $4\times4=16.$

If $x$ does not have to be an integer then there are infinite number of solutions as you can let $n_x={4\over x}$ be any integer and then $n_y=4n_x$ is also an integer.

However the greatest $x$ is still $16$ because since $n_x$ must be an integer it has to be at least $1$, which implies $x\leq4$.

Comment: But $x$ need not be an integer itself. We were not told that the tiles would have sidelengths that are integer multiples of one meter.

Comment: Ok slow down there  Jyrki Lahtonen, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: How did you reach the conlusion: "Both of them must be integers so $x=1,2,4$ are the only possibilities."

Comment: Edited the answer to support non-integer length tiles.